# not getting any response when connecting to firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase-admin npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin.

below is my firebase initialization code.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const serviceAccount = require('/config/firebase/..json');

const fcmInitialize = {
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount, agent),
  databaseURL: config.get('FIREBASE_URL')
};
admin.database.enableLogging(true);

if (config.get('NODE_ENV') !== 'development') {
  fcmInitialize.httpAgent = agent;
  fcmInitialize.httpsAgent = agent;
  fcmInitialize.proxy = false;
}

const fcm = admin.initializeApp(fcmInitialize);
```

and below I'm trying to connect to my firebase and get into chatrooms database.

```
await fcm.auth();
const database = await fcm.database();

console.log('initiate chatrooms');
const chatroomPath = await database.ref(`chatrooms/${userId}`);
let chatrooms;
await chatroomPath.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value', async snapshot => {
  console.log('enter chatrooms');
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    chatrooms = await snapshot.val();
    console.log(chatrooms);
  }
});
console.log(`chatrooms: ${chatrooms}`);
```

I'm not getting any error, and when I check the logging terminal, only 'initiate chatrooms' gets logged, and after that no response until my API reach timeout. Is it normal in Firebase Admin SDK to not receive any logs when there's an error, or am I missing something?

I tried adding `admin.database.enableLogging(true);` in hopes it would log any error, but nothing appears on the logging terminal, so I don't have any idea where to start.

Comment: Try without `async-await` in the `.once` callback function. Eg: `.once('value', snapshot => {  /* do something */ })`

Comment: what made you think that might be the cause @ShriHariL?

Comment: Because the handlers must be expecting a function reference, but now it might be getting a Promise. Async function is actually a Promise. But I am not sure this will work. Did you try it? Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Okay.. I am wrong. Async function's return value is Promise and not the function itself. Sorry for the confustion, it should be an another issue.

Answer (score 0):

First up: stop sprinkling `await` on every line. You should only use `await` when the function actually returns a Promise, and you want to wait for that promise to resolve in the current code block. Of the 5 `await` lines in your second code block, 0 actually accomplish anything meaningful.

---

The reason your log doesn't show any chatrooms is because it runs before the data is retrieved. And the reasons for that, is that you're passing a callback to `once` rather then waiting for the callback. You should do one *or* the other, not both.

A simple fix without any `await`:

```
fcm.auth(); //  Remove await, because this call does not return a promise
const database = fcm.database(); //  Remove await, because this call does not return a promise

console.log('initiate chatrooms');
const chatroomPath = database.ref(`chatrooms/${userId}`); //  Remove await, because this call does not return a promise
chatroomPath.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value', snapshot => { //  Remove await, because you're not using the promise. Remove async, because we're not using await inside the callback.
  console.log('enter chatrooms');
  let chatrooms;
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    chatrooms = snapshot.val(); //  Remove await, because this call does not return a promise
    console.log(chatrooms);
  }
  console.log(`chatrooms: ${chatrooms}`); //  Move into the callback, so that it runs after the data is loaded
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `await`, you only need **one** of those, on the call to `once`:

```
fcm.auth();
const database = fcm.database();

console.log('initiate chatrooms');
const chatroomPath = database.ref(`chatrooms/${userId}`);
let chatrooms;
              //   Use await to wait for the snapshot from the promise
const snapshot = await chatroomPath.orderByChild('timestamp').once('value');, 
if (snapshot.val()) {
  chatrooms = snapshot.val();
}
console.log(`chatrooms: ${chatrooms}`);
```

So now the code actually gets the snapshot from `once` by using `await`, and no longer needs to pass a callback.

Comment: thank you for your input, but there's still no log. I've even added try catch on once method but also no log. 

I have a feeling it's a problem with the infrastructure of the application project I'm working on, but since I'm still new to both the project and firebase, I have no idea where to look. I have asked the infrastructure engineers but they're also fairly new to the project and all the seniors are no longer in this company. Unfortunately they are also not familiar with our firebase infrastructure.

Comment: First things first: does the explanation I gave in my answer on why you don't need all those `await` statements make sense? Does it also make sense *why* your ```console.log(`chatrooms: ${chatrooms}`);``` doesn't work, after reading my answer?